# Force Qt custom signal to be processed immediately?

Tags: c++, qt, signals-slots

I have a question about Qt and its signals/slots mechanism.
I have created a custom widget and in that I have created a custom `SIGNAL` (ShowMessage). This signal is connected to a `SLOT`, which displays the message (along with the specified timeout) in my main window's status bar.

Now, I have an operation in my class that takes a long time to execute, and it's blocking the UI. I was hoping to `emit` my signal before starting the operation and when it's finished, `emit` it again to update the status bar; something like this:

```
emit ShowMessage(message, timeout);
// Do the long operation
emit ShowMessage(newMessage, timeout);
```

But my problem is that it seems that Qt waits until the whole operation is finished, and only updates the status bar with `newMessage`.
Is there a way to somehow "force" immediate processing of my signal, because if I want to resort to threads, then my life will get much more complicated!

Comment: What is this long operation? Why is it difficult to move it to a new thread?

Comment: Are you connecting using Qt::DirectConnection? - this should ensure that your signal is processed immediately already. If it is not then you should use the debugger to step through and see what is happening. I am assuming that this all occurs in the same GUI thread?

Comment: Sorry, but I don't understand what you mean by `Qt::DirectionConnection`. I'm new to Qt and I'm using it as a container for my OpenGL drawings.

Comment: @thuga The long operation is actually OpenGL calls to load a model (and buffer its data); I'm not sure how it can be done in a separate thread

Answer (score 5):

> Is there a way to somehow "force" immediate processing of my signal

**Yes**, there is. :-).
After you show your first message, call [`QCoreApplication::processEvents()`](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qcoreapplication.html#processEvents). This forces all pending events to be processed at the point of call. For example,

```
emit ShowMessage(message, timeout);
QCoreApplication::processEvents();
// Do the long operation
emit ShowMessage(newMessage, timeout);
```

Comment: Thank you so much for your answer :)
It fixed the initial problem, but it created another problem in my application. I don't know how familiar you are with OpenGL, but I'm calling native API OpengGL methods in my application, and now I receive "access violation error" when calling `glDrawElements`. Do you have an idea what's happening here?
I have no idea what the connection is between adding this method and my OpenGL calls

Comment: @Farzad You are coding synchronously. Don't, and your problems will go away. Everything that is called from the event loop (so, all your slots that connect to Qt's signals) needs to run quickly to completion. Your signal *is* processed immediately, but since you block the event loop, the widget never gets a chance to repaint itself. You must not block the event loop. If you need to do long processing in the GUI thread, do it in small chunks as a reaction to a zero-duration timer expiring. Do not recurse into `processEvents`, it's can reenter your code and I consider it bad advice.

Comment: @KubaOber Can you please elaborate a little more on the timer you're mentioning? I'm new to Qt, and I'm using it as a container to call OpenGL functions. My "long" operation is actually loading (and buffering) a model from a file, so I don't know what you mean by using a timer

Comment: @Farzad Break up your long operation into many short operations. To start the operation(s), you can `connect(new QTimer(this), &QTimer::timeout, this, &MyClass::myOperation)`. `myOperation` should do a chunk of work every time it's called, and return. When it's done doing the work, it should cancel the timer by doing `delete sender()`. That'd be the minimal way of doing it as a proof of concept, you of course don't need a dynamically allocated timer for that.

Comment: So, is there a way to do something like this: create a timer and start the operation, and know from the timer that the operation is finished? I mean, a way to somehow wait for the operation to be finished and continue what we were doing before